# I'll be in Africa for one year: What is the most effective combination of programs to add mass?

Tags: weightlifting, muscle-mass

I have access to a standard gym in Africa, and will be here for one year.  What program or combination of programs would provide the largest physique changes for when I return to the states?

Comment: How many days per week (and hours per day) are you willing or able to spend in the gym? What have you done exercise-wise before you went to Africa, why can't you continue that program?

Comment: You question basically is: "What is the most effective program to add mass?", The Africa part is irrelevant as you said that you have access to a _standard gym_, which should have all equipment needed for all standard programs.

Comment: Do no exercise, and eat a calorie surplus of 500 cal per day. Over a year your physique will definitely change. Not positively, mind you, but you'll be larger.

Answer (score 1):

Heavy compound exercises, e.g. squats, deadlifts, pullups.., are always good for building mass.
Depending on your progression it makes sense that you do a full body workout (squat/lift, pushing and pull on every training day) or a split (1 day push, 1 day legs, 1 day pull).

Optionally you can add isolation exercises in order to remove imbalances.

And remember: Never skip leg exercises.